# How to set two variables as onevariable

Tags: php, variables, post, dynamic, isset

I have this question, and i can't find any radical answer...

So, is there any possibility to set two variable in one variable

```
if ($post) {
    $'item_name'. $x .' = $_POST['item_name'. $x .''];
}
```

if `x = 1` then,
$item_name1 = $_POST['item_name1'];
that's the bahivor I want to implement, a way to wright the first part of the post.

the main issue item_namex  (x) could be 1, 2, 3, 4 ext

Comment: Can you post a desired output

Comment: Not clear what are you trying to do ? Are you assigning  post variable .

Comment: yes that's what iwant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [variable variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) in PHP:

```
$x = 7;
$var = 'item_name' . $x;
$$var = $_POST['item_name'. $x];
```

and then you get `$item_name7` with value you want. Also trailing concatenation of `.''` in your right side of assignment is useless

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value){
    $$key=$value;
}
```

For every $key variable will be created and $value would be assigned to it